# Understanding git diff on files

Tags: git, git-diff

What does the folowing output of `git diff` mean?

```
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 24aa464..49c20f4 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
 LINE1
-LINE2
 LINE3
```

I think I understand that the "-" new LINE2 means that the version on have in workspace does not have the LINE2 that is in staging, but what does `@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@` mean??

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format

Comment: sorry I made a better example but still not getting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the line ranges that the diff is concerned with for that hunk, meaning lines 1 to 3 in a/README.md and lines 1 to 2 in b/README.md.

Comment: sorry I dont get it.. if the 2nd line was remove then ?

Comment: Whether or not a line was removed isn't relevant. The line `@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@` means "lines 1 to 3 in the original file and lines 1 to 2 in the resulting file are affected by the following changes". If you had only changed the text "LINE2" to "LINE2 new stuff", it would look like `@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@`.